# Integration by parts in two dimensions.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I was wondering if someone could help me. I have the formula for integration by parts in 2D,
\begin{equation}
\iint_{\Omega} u (\nabla \cdot \nabla v)d\Omega=\int_{\Gamma}u(\nabla v.\mathbf{n})d\Gamma-\iint_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot\nabla v d\Omega
\end{equation}

Then by setting $u=u(x,y)$ and $v=v(x)$,
\begin{equation}
\iint_{\Omega}u\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}d\Omega=\int_{\Gamma}u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}n_xd\Gamma-\iint_{\Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} d\Omega
\end{equation}

By setting $w=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$,
\begin{equation}
\iint_{\Omega}u\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}d\Omega=\int_{\Gamma}uwn_xd\Gamma-\iint_{\Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}w d\Omega
\end{equation}

I haven't been able to find a book providing me with any constraints on the functions $u$ and $v$, or $u$ and $w$. I imagine that I need some constraints on the number of times the functions are continuously differentiable etc. Any references would be of great help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you just asking for what constraints you need on $u,v$ for this to hold?

Comment: Yes that's it exactly. A reference for these conditions would be really useful as well. This formula arises from using 1D integration by parts on the inner integral as well, but I didn't want to just constrain u and v using the constraints of 1D integration by parts.

Comment: It seems to me that you need $v$ twice continuously differentiable with respect to $x$, and you need $u$ to have continuous partial derivatives.